# Comparison of Explain Statement Output on Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, optimization, amazon-redshift, temp-tables, explain

I have written a very complicated query in **Amazon Redshift** which comprises of 3-4 temporary tables along with sub-queries.Since, Query is slow in execution, I tried to replace it with another query, which uses **derived tables** instead of temporary tables.
I just want to ask, Is there any way to compare the "**Explain**" Output for both the queries, so that we can conclude which query is working better in performance(both **space** and **time**). 
Also, how much helpful is replacing **temporary tables** with **derived tables** in redshift ?

Comment: To compare the explain, do "explain (analyse, costs, timing, buffers, verbose, format json)" then you can compare using a side-by-side diff tool, or do a blink-comparison using pev http://tatiyants.com/postgres-query-plan-visualization/

Comment: what do you mean by derived tables vs temporary tables? please explain that part fully as well and if you can - show your sql.

Comment: @JonScott My query is like : " With patient_set as (select * from .........2-3 joins......), metric_set as (select * from......... 2-3 joins......), measure as (select * from......... 2-3 joins......) select x,y,z from patient_set  join on ..... join metric_set  on........ join measure  on........ where............   <br> Now second query is build in such a way that temp tables are replaced by derived tables.

Comment: please update your question to include your query AND explain what do you mean by derived tables vs temporary tables?

Comment: @Ben Thanks!!! Pev is helpful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Redshift generates it's own temporary tables (visible in the plan) then you may be able to tune the query by creating them as temporary tables yourself, specifying compression and adding distribution and sort keys that help with joins done on the table.

Very slow queries typically use a `nested loop` join style. The fastest join type is a `merge join`. If possible, rewrite the query or modify the  tables to use `merge join` or at least `hash join`. Details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-performance-improvement-opportunities.html

Resources to better understand Redshift query planning and execution:

- Query Planning And Execution Workflow:

  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-query-planning.html
- Reviewing Query Plan Steps:

  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/reviewing-query-plan-steps.html
- Mapping the Query Plan to the Query Summary:

  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-plan-summary-map.html
- Diagnostic Queries for Query Tuning:

  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/diagnostic-queries-for-query-tuning.html