# New to Redshift: Basic Query Tuning Questions

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm taking a deep dive into Redshift query tuning.  I'm brand new to the technology.   I have a few basic questions and some loosely-formed interpretations I'm hoping some my confirm or refute.

Here it goes...

1. Distribution vs Broadcast operations:
   So far, I haven't found anything in the manual that conclusively tells me the difference.  What I'm noticing from the Plan is that if I choose the distribution style ALL, I still see BCAST operations happening.   Can someone please explain the difference between these operations?
2. Nodes vs Slices:
   I'm noticing the manual, in the context of distribution operations, at one point it indicates data is distributed across nodes and at another point it indicates data is distributed across slices.   I'm analyzing the plan in a dev environment with one node and two slices.   Here's my loosely-formed interpretation:
   The optimizer is node agnostic; it cares about slices.  Data can be distributed to a node incidental to a slice being resident of that target node.  Can someone confirm or refute this?
3. High Cardinality Joins
   I'm attempt to tune two large transaction tables with multiple, high cardinality join operations (no primary/foreign key).  Went through several, variegated iterations involving dist styles and sortkeys in addition to reading several blogs on tuning.
   Loosely formed interpretation: Redshift excels as star/snowflake schemas in which joins are typically low cardinality (Dims and fact tables) but struggles with transactional tables.   Can someone confirm or refute this?

I appreciate your insights.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This subject is probably too broad to be addressed in a single Q/A.

1. Broadcast for dist all is different from other broadcast - the data is already on every node. Distribution means that, to complete the join,  Redshift **re**distributes the data across all slices using a new dist key.
2. Nodes are subdivided into slices. Most query operators work at the slice level.
3. Redshift can complete huge joins on disk resident data faster than any other system I've used (YMMV). For maximum speed huge joins should be done on tables with the same dist and sort keys - using the dist and sort key columns. [See the "Merge Join" note here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-performance-improvement-opportunities.html#hash-join)

[From a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558782/comparison-of-explain-statement-output-on-amazon-redshift/49734358#49734358), these links should provide the explanations you need:

- Query Planning And Execution Workflow:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-query-planning.html
- Reviewing Query Plan Steps:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/reviewing-query-plan-steps.html
- Mapping the Query Plan to the Query Summary:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-plan-summary-map.html
- Diagnostic Queries for Query Tuning:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/diagnostic-queries-for-query-tuning.html